# Why the UI change can not update the database? Which part is wrong in my logic?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, user-interface

This is my first time doing java. In my java project, I'm doing a Mental Health Incident Manager program, in which it can extract the data from people's survey response that's saved in a CSV file.

First, I want the report_history4 database to first insert the data from the CSV file. And if there's no new record in the CSV file, means don't need to insert anything new. In the database, I have a column called emRate, where I initialized it to 0 and I want a admin to be able to change it.

Next, I want to update the value of newRate after the admin click on the button save, not inserting a new row, not applying to every row, just update the newRate for that specific student and incident. And After that, I want the database to maintain that new value even I reopen the database and insert new data again.

However, my code now are not processing my thought, after I click on save, the data is not updated in the database. It's a mess. Please help me to solve the problem.

I have the method of updateRateForIncident, isRowUpdated, insertRecordIntoDatabase,SurveyIDExists to make sure solving my update proble, but the method doesn't work.

This is my code of inserting and updating database:

```
public void fetchDataFromCSVAndInsertIntoDatabase(matching Matching, int newRate) throws IOException, CsvValidationException {
Connection c = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
CSVReader reader = null;

        try {
            // Connect to the database
            c = table_Connect();
            c.setAutoCommit(false); // Set auto-commit to false
    
            // Prepare the SQL query for inserting or updating records
            String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO report_history4 (Student, Year, EmRate, Incident, ID, Date) " +
                    "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    
            // Read the CSV file
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("/Users/alex.zhang2018qd.ycef.com/OneDrive - Yew Chung International School HK/CSIA database/Table1.csv"));
            System.out.println("Reading data from CSV file...");
            String[] nextLine;
    
            // Skipping the first line assuming it's the header
            reader.skip(1);
    
            // Read each line of the CSV file and insert or update into the database
            boolean newRecordInserted = false;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                if (nextLine.length == 0) {
                    // Skip empty lines
                    continue;
                }
    
                // Extract the data from the columns
                String SurveyIncident = nextLine[17];
                String SurveyEmail = nextLine[3];
                String SurveyIDString = nextLine[2];
                int SurveyID;
    
                try {
                    SurveyID = Integer.parseInt(SurveyIDString);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid SurveyID found: " + SurveyIDString);
                    // Handle this case as needed, such as skipping this record or logging the error
                    continue; // Skip to the next iteration of the loop
                }
    
                double serialDate = 0.0; // Initialize serialDate to a default value
                if (!nextLine[18].isEmpty()) {
                    serialDate = Double.parseDouble(nextLine[18]);
                }
                String submissionDate = convertSerialDateToReadableDate(serialDate);
    
    
                if (SurveyID != 0) {
                    if (!SurveyIDExists(c, SurveyID)) {
                        // Insert a new record into the database only if it's not marked as updated
                        if (!isRowUpdated(c, SurveyID, SurveyIncident)) {
                            insertRecordIntoDatabase(c, insertQuery, Matching, SurveyEmail, SurveyID, SurveyIncident, submissionDate, newRate);
                            newRecordInserted = true;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Skipping insertion for ID: " + SurveyID + ", Incident: " + SurveyIncident + " as it's marked as updated.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    
            if (!newRecordInserted) {
                System.out.println("No new records found in CSV.");
            }
    
            // Commit the transaction
            c.commit();
        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // Rollback the transaction if an exception occurs
            try {
                if (c != null)
                    c.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null)
                    reader.close();
                if (statement != null)
                    statement.close();
                if (c != null)
                    c.close();
            } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void updateRateForIncident(Connection c, String query, int newRate, int ID, String incident) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
    
        try {
            statement = c.prepareStatement(query);
    
            // Set the parameters for the prepared statement
            statement.setInt(1, newRate);
            statement.setInt(2, ID);
            statement.setString(3, incident);
    
            // Execute the SQL statement
            int rowsUpdated = statement.executeUpdate();
    
            if (rowsUpdated > 0) {
                // Data updated successfully
                System.out.println("Data updated in report history4 successfully!");
                // Set the updated_flag for the updated row
                String updateFlagQuery = "UPDATE report_history4 SET updated_flag = TRUE WHERE ID = ? AND Incident = ?";
                PreparedStatement updateFlagStatement = c.prepareStatement(updateFlagQuery);
                updateFlagStatement.setInt(1, ID);
                updateFlagStatement.setString(2, incident);
                updateFlagStatement.executeUpdate();
                updateFlagStatement.close();
            } else {
                // Handle case where no rows were updated
                System.out.println("No rows updated in report history4 for ID: " + ID + ", Incident: " + incident);
            }
        } finally {
            if (statement != null) {
                statement.close();
            }
        }
    }
    
    private boolean isRowUpdated(Connection c, int ID, String incident) throws SQLException {
        String query = "SELECT updated_flag FROM report_history4 WHERE ID = ? AND Incident = ?";
        try (PreparedStatement statement = c.prepareStatement(query)){
            statement.setInt(1, ID);
            statement.setString(2, incident);
            try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                if (resultSet.next()) {
                    return resultSet.getBoolean("updated_flag");
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    private void insertRecordIntoDatabase(Connection connection, String query, matching Matching, String SurveyEmail, int SurveyID, String SurveyIncident, String submissionDate, int newRate) throws SQLException {
        // Call the matching method to get student information
        Student student = matching.checkStudent(SurveyEmail);
    
        if (student != null) {
            // Find student that reported on the student list
            String name = student.getName();
            String yearGroup = student.getYearGroup();
            System.out.println("Student found: " + name + ", " + yearGroup);
    
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    
            // Set the parameters for the prepared statement
            statement.setString(1, name);
            statement.setString(2, yearGroup);
            
            // Check if the row is marked as updated
            boolean rowUpdated = isRowUpdated(connection, SurveyID, SurveyIncident);
            
            // Insert newRate only if the row is not marked as updated
            if (!rowUpdated) {
                statement.setInt(3, newRate);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Skipping insertion of newRate for ID: " + SurveyID + ", Incident: " + SurveyIncident + " as it's marked as updated.");
            }
            
            statement.setString(4, SurveyIncident);
            statement.setInt(5, SurveyID);
            statement.setString(6, submissionDate);
    
            // Execute the SQL statement
            statement.executeUpdate();
    
            statement.close();
        } else {
            // Handle the case where the student is not found
            System.out.println("Student not found for email: " + SurveyEmail);
        }
    }
    
    private boolean SurveyIDExists(Connection c,  int SurveyID) throws SQLException {
        if (SurveyID == 0) {
            // If the SurveyID is empty and it's not the first time insert, return false
            return false;
        } else {
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM report_history4 WHERE ID = ?";
            try (PreparedStatement statement = c.prepareStatement(query)){
                // Parse SurveyID into an integer               
                statement.setInt(1, SurveyID);
                try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
                    if (resultSet.next()) {
                        int count = resultSet.getInt(1);
                        return count > 0;
                    }
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Handle parsing error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is the code where I click on the save button  to update value in database:

```
if (isAdmin) {
Save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
Connection c = null;
try {
// Get the selected item from the RateComboBox
int newRate = Integer.parseInt((String) RateComboBox.getSelectedItem());

                        // Connect to the database
                        c = table_Connect();
    
                        // Call the updateRateForIncident method to update the database
                        String query = "UPDATE report_history4 SET EmRate = ? WHERE ID = ? AND Incident = ?";
                        history.updateRateForIncident(c, query, newRate, ID, incident);
                        System.out.println("Update successful");
    
                        // Fetch data from the database to refresh the JTable
                        history.fetchDataFromDatabase();
    
                        // Show a message confirming changes
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Changes saved successfully!");
    
                        frame.setVisible(false);
                        report_history2 nw2;
                        try {
                            nw2 = new report_history2(isAdmin, newRate);
                            nw2.setVisible(true);
                        } catch (CsvValidationException | IOException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        
                        
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid rate format!");
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error occurred while saving changes!");
                    } finally {
                        // Close the database connection
                        if (c != null) {
                            try {
                                c.close();
                            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```